# How to make random balls fall from above in SpriteKit (Swift)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to make balls to fall with random positions and directions in SpriteKit with Swift

i have code that worked in objective-c but i am trying to modify it to work in swift

i used this code for randomness

```
func randomInRange(low: CGFloat, high: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
let value = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX)
return value * (high - low) + low
}
```

for falling method

```
//  some constants for the angle and speed values that i am going to use when setting a ball's velocity:

var kCCHaloLowAngle : CGFloat  = (200.0 * 3.14) / 180.0;
    var kCCHaloHighAngle : CGFloat  = (340.0 * 3.14) / 180.0;
    var kCCHaloSpeed: CGFloat = 100.0;

func spawnHaloo ()->()
    {
        // Create ball node.
        let ball : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball")
        halo.position = CGPointMake(randomInRange(ball.size.width * 0.5, high: self.size.width - (ball.size.width * 0.5)),
            self.size.height + (ball.size.height * 0.5));
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/2)
        let direction : CGVector  = radiansToVector(randomInRange(kCCHaloLowAngle, high: kCCHaloHighAngle));
        ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(direction.dx * kCCHaloSpeed, direction.dy * kCCHaloSpeed);
        ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0;
        ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0;
        ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0;
    }


 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    let action1 = (SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0, withRange: 1.0))
    let action2 = SKAction.runBlock(spawnHaloo)
    let spawnHalo : SKAction = SKAction.sequence([action1,action2])

    let action3 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnHalo)
    self.runAction(action3)

}
```

the difference between the objective-c code and this code in swift is this line

```
[SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnHalo) onTarget:self]
```

instead of it i used

```
let action2 = SKAction.runBlock(spawnHaloo)
```

because when i use it in swift it gives me this error

```
Cannot invoke 'performSelector' with an argument list of type '(selector: (), onTarget: AnyObject.Protocol)'
```

maybe the problem here anyone can help ?

Comment: i replaced the word "halo" with "ball" so i can describe better and i forget to replace one here its okay not the problem